# Why can't I access params in TabRouter in react-navigation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In [react-navigation](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation) I am navigating doing `props.navigate("Page", { index: 1 })` in a react component.

So I am creating a `TabRouter` with `createNavigator` in a way like this:

```
import {
    TabRouter,
    createNavigator
} from "react-navigation";

createNavigator(TabRouter(Page: {
    screen: Page,
    path: "page/:page"
}))(NavView)
```

Then I can't access to `navigation.state.params.index`, but **I can** if using `StackRouter` instead.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not previously available. [This pull request](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/pull/134) aimed to add `setState` to `TabRouter` -- it got added in mid-April 2017.